# Can prerequisites in a static pattern rule be filtered?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to limit $(all_possible_inputs) to $(relevant_inputs). $(all_possible_inputs) is a concatenation of multiple files from other included makefiles. The following functions correctly (the perl scripts know how to ignore the extra inputs), but everything is rebuilt if a single input changes:

```
$(step2_outputs): $(data)/%.step2: $(routines)/step2.%.pl $(all_possible_inputs)
        perl $^ > $@
```

**UPDATE**: Filter must match more than one *.step1 file. If step1 produced:

```
A.foo.step1
A.bar.step1
B.foo.step1
B.bar.step1
B.baz.step1
```

Then step2's rules should expand to:

```
A.step2: routines/step2.A.pl A.foo.step1 A.bar.step1
B.step2: routines/step2.B.pl B.foo.step1 B.bar.step1 B.baz.step1
```

Logically, this is what I want to work:

```
$(step2_outputs): $(data)/%.step2: $(routines)/step2.%.pl $(filter $(data)/%.*.step1,$(all_possible_inputs))
        perl $^ > $@
```

The % is supposed to match the static pattern rule stem. The * is supposed to be a wildcard (which I'm aware won't work). I believe the problem is that filter repurposes '%', so the filter expression fails. I thought it might be solvable with Secondary Expansion, but I tried this, and the filter still returned the empty string:

**UPDATE**: I switched the examples to use $$* based on Beta's good suggestion:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(step2_outputs): $(data)/%.step2: $(routines)/step2.%.pl $$(filter $(data)/$$*.%.step1,$(all_possible_inputs))
        perl $^ > $@
```

This is running on gnu make 3.81 in a linux environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your third method works for me, but you can try this: instead of `%` (which is expanded in the first phase) use `$$*`

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(step2_outputs): $(data)/%.step2: $(routines)/step2.%.pl $$(filter $(data)/$$*.step1,$(all_possible_inputs))
    perl $^ > $@
```

Comment: $$* is expanding to the correct value, thank you. Any idea how to mix $$* and %? I oversimplified the example and now realize one of the complications I removed was necessary. I need filter to match one or more files containing what $$* expands to (i.e. "match.foo.step1" and "match.bar.step1" but not "miss.foo.step1" or "miss.bar.step1". $$*.foo.step1 works, but $$*.%.step1 does not.

Comment: To also use a % sign, define your percent sign as a variable and use that in your second expansion prerequisites ex:
PERCENT = %
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(targets): %: $$(filter $$*.$$(PERCENT))